# Fetch returns undefined the first time a user signs in

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-redux, firebase-authentication

I sort of know why it happens, but not sure how to go on about solving it.

I have a React project that uses Cloud Firestore as database, and I have a simple login-page where you can sign in via your Google account. The first time you sign in a new document gets added to the "users" collection in Firebase.

After the document has been created it fetches that user data from Firebase and stores it in Redux.

```
const signInWithGoogle = async () => {
    try {
        const res = await signInWithPopup(auth, googleProvider);
        const user = res.user;
        const q = query(collection(db, "users"), where("uid", "==", user.uid));
        const docs = await getDocs(q);
        if(docs.docs.length === 0){
            const firstName = user.displayName.split(' ')[0];
            await addDoc(collection(db, "users"), {
                uid: user.uid,
                name: user.displayName,
                firstName: firstName,
                photoURL: user.photoURL,
                authProvider: "google",
                email: user.email,
            })
            dispatch(getUser(user))
        }
    } catch(err) {
        console.error(err);
        alert(err.message);
    }
}
```

I also check whenever the user's auth state changes (here I also do another fetch and store it in Redux).

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = auth.onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      setCurrentUser(user);
      setLoading(false);
      if(user){
        dispatch(getUser(user))
      } else {
        console.log("user logout")
      }
    });
    return unsubscribe;
  }, []);
```

But when a new user signs in the first time, I get an error from the fetch:

```
export const getUser = createAsyncThunk("profile/getUser", async (user) => {
  try {
    const userQuery = query(
      collection(db, "users"),
      where("uid", "==", user?.uid)
    );
    const doc = await getDocs(userQuery);
    const data = doc.docs[0].data();
    return data;
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
    alert("An error occured while fetching user data");
  }
});
```

"data" in above block is undefined for a small moment when the user signs in, so the alert in the try/catch block always goes off (it does manage to fetch the data after though).
This error only happens when it's a new user.

I understand that the fetch occurs before a document has been created in the "users" collection, but I'm not sure how to solve this. I've tried to add if/else to certain parts of the code (but just felt like I was grasping for straws).

I'm very much new to Firebase and still learning React, so every bit of help is really appreciated!

Comment: is the signin with google called in a useEffect by any chance

Comment: No, on the login-page there's a button with an onClick function that looks like this:

`const handleGoogleSignIn = async () => {
    try {
      setLoading(true);
      await signInWithGoogle()
      navigate("/")
    } catch(err) {
      alert("Failed to login");
    }

    setLoading(false);
  }`


(sorry dont know how to format the code)

Comment: Not sure if it's worth mentioning, but `signInWithGoogle` and `useEffect` functions in the original post is in a context file (AuthContext) and AuthProvider is wrapped around my routes in App.js.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is that your `signInWithGoogle` & `useEffect` both are running on user's auth status change. And, when its the new user, `signInWithGoogle` function makes aysnc call to create default doc, whereas `useEffect` runs to `dispatch` action, but at that moment user doesn't have any linked document. That is why you are getting `undefined`.

Ideally, you should remove one. You can merge the useEffect into signInWithGoogle to set the `user` details and `dispatch` as well.

```
const signInWithGoogle = async () => {
    try {
        const res = await signInWithPopup(auth, googleProvider);
        const user = res.user;
        const q = query(collection(db, "users"), where("uid", "==", user.uid));
        const docs = await getDocs(q);

        // create `doc` if its the new user
        if(docs.docs.length === 0){
            const firstName = user.displayName.split(' ')[0];
            await addDoc(collection(db, "users"), {
                uid: user.uid,
                name: user.displayName,
                firstName: firstName,
                photoURL: user.photoURL,
                authProvider: "google",
                email: user.email,
            })
        }
        
        // set user info and dispatch
        setCurrentUser(user);
        setLoading(false);
        dispatch(getUser(user))
    } catch(err) {
        console.error(err);
        alert(err.message);
    }
}
```

Hope that answers your query.

Thanks